# How to create a pointer with value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am currently trying to create a pointer which points to an array (in C), due to my use-case i need to do this all from pointer operations. My final desired output is a pointer of type uint8_t which points to an array of elements with a value i determine, but this does not seem to be working.

Here is the code i use to create this:

```
uint8_t* create_array_uint8(int height,int width, uint8_t value, int print_array = 0){
    int size = height*width * sizeof(uint8_t);
    uint8_t* array;
    array = (uint8_t*) malloc(size);

    int total_elements = height* width;
    int count = 0;

    uint8_t* val_ptr;
    val_ptr = array;
    while (count<total_elements){
        val_ptr = val_ptr + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
        *val_ptr = value;
        count++;
    }

    if (print_array == 1){
        int count = 0;

        uint8_t* print_ptr;
        print_ptr = array;
        while (count<total_elements){
            print_ptr = print_ptr + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
            printf("The %d element has a value of ---> %d \n",count,*print_ptr);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Here is me using this function:

```
    uint8_t* A = create_array_uint8(3,3,1,1);
```

i.e i am creating a a pointer of type uint8_t that points to an array with 9 uint8_t elements whose value is 1. However my output is the following:

```
root@a7b006267463:# nvcc test.cu 
root@a7b006267463:# ./a.out 
The 0 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 1 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 2 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 3 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 4 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 5 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 6 element has a value of ---> 1 
The 7 element has a value of ---> 0 
The 8 element has a value of ---> 37
```

Which is different to the printed value i expected, of all elements having the value of 1. Im not sure where im going wrong, i would appreciate if someone could provide some guidance.

Comment: That looks like C to me. Why C++ tag?

Comment: `val_ptr` is advanced by one first, pointing to `array[1]`. Then by two, pointing to `array[3]`. Then by three, pointing to `array[6]`. This continues with ever larger stride; pretty soon, it gets out of bounds and the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Seems like a typo. Should be adding `count * sizeof(uint8_t)` to **`array`** instead of to `val_ptr` and `print_ptr`. Or leave it as adding to `val_ptr` and `print_ptr`, but add **`sizeof(uint8_t)`** instead of `count * sizeof(uint8_t)`. Either method works, but don't mix them together.

Comment: just `++val_ptr;` in the end of loop instead of `val_ptr = val_ptr + count * sizeof(uint8_t);`, same with `print_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following 2 lines:

```
val_ptr = val_ptr + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
print_ptr = print_ptr + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
```

These two lines were accessing out of the allocated memory.

Please try:

```
val_ptr = array + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
print_ptr = array + count * sizeof(uint8_t);
```